# Breadth first search of C# Control Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion, queue, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to write an extension method for `System.Web.UI.Control` which will search its `ControlCollection` for an instance of specific `Type`, and return the first instance found. Depth-first is simple, however I want to search breadth first so that higher collections take priority.

My current method is flawed and will exit early, returning null in certain cases where the entire search wasn't completed. I'm hoping I'm close to the right solution but need some fresh eyes on it. Any suggestions?

```
public static T FindFirstControlOfType<T>(this Control rootControl, bool searchRecursively) where T : Control
{
    // list for container controls
    List<Control> controlsWithChildren = new List<Control>();

    // iterate the current control collection first
    foreach (Control child in rootControl.Controls)
    {
        if (child.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            return (T)child;
        }

        // track those controls containing children
        if (child.HasControls())
        {
            controlsWithChildren.Add(child);
        }
    }

    // if recursion is enabled, search the child nodes
    if (searchRecursively)
    {
        foreach (Control control in controlsWithChildren)
        {
            return FindFirstControlOfType<T>(control, true);
        }
    }

    // if never found, return null
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT - Working Solution based on the marked answer, for anyone interested:**

```
public static T FindFirstControlOfType<T>(this Control rootControl, bool searchNestedControls) where T : Control
{
    Queue<Control> queue = new Queue<Control>();

    EnqueueChildControls(queue, rootControl);
    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        Control current = queue.Dequeue();

        if (current.GetType() == typeof(T))
        {
            return (T)current;
        }

        if (searchNestedControls)
        {
            EnqueueChildControls(queue, current);
        }
    }
    return null;

}

private static void EnqueueChildControls(Queue<Control> queue, Control control)
{
    foreach (Control current in control.Controls)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(current);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Breadth first search (pseudo code)

```
Queue fringe 

fringe.Enqueue(rootControl)

while(fringe.Count > 0)
{
    current = fringe.Dequeue()
    Visit(current)
    fringe.EnqueueAll(current.Children)
}
```

There's no need for recursion for breadth first search.

`Visit` is whatever you want to do with the current object. If you're searching for something then `Visit` would mean: `if(current matches criteria) return current`

Update: 
Working example: https://gist.github.com/1960108

Comment: Thanks Andre - I will try implementing this. It's been a while since I needed a breadth first search so I'm rusty.

Comment: So was I, but recently I needed to do a BFS and then I remembered that it was dead easy to implement. Good luck, if you need help let us know.

Comment: On a side note, you can change this BFS to a depth first by just changing the queue to a Stack, rather than using recursion.  You can also make it a best first search by using a priority queue.  If you have a common interface for all of them you can get to the point where a simple configuration change alters the entire algorithm.  Cool stuff.

Comment: @AndreLoker Thanks - I used your guidance to rewrite the method and it works perfectly. Upvote + Answer. I'll update my question with the final code, which may help someone in the future.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for this suggestion - I actually like the flexibility and may refactor my extension method to support search types. Back to the good old days of first-in-first-out vs. .... :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the main problem is here:

```
foreach (Control control in controlsWithChildren)
{
    return FindFirstControlOfType<T>(control, true);
}
```

You are ***returning*** the results of the recursive search on the very first child with children, regardless of whether that search succeeded.  Breadth-first search is a widely-discussed topic, but it boils down to using a queue:

```
Queue<Control> controlsWithChildren = new Queue<Control>();
```

and (usually) a loop rather than recursion.